# Unable to send packets via RAW_SOCK on OSX

Tags: python, macos, sockets, raw-sockets, darwin

After quite a bit of searching and reading docs, I've hit a bit of a wall when using `RAW_SOCK` on OSX to send custom IPv4 + UDP packets using family `AF_INET`

Given the sample code (in python) below:

```
import socket

ip_packet = <full code below> 

raw_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
raw_sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
raw_sock.sendto(ip_header + udp_header, ("1.1.1.1", 0))
```

I'm getting `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`. I suspect there is something slightly off with how I'm constructing the IP packet, however given this works on Linux and all other BSDs, I'm not entirely sure which parts of the header I've constructed incorrectly. The only field

Are there any docs covering Darwins `RAW_SOCK`? Specifically what headers should be what values(And endianness?)

I pulled some rough code together here which illustrates what Im trying to do: [link](https://pastebin.com/XM9bAsnU)

Comment: In the code at the link you assign `ip_header` two times, is that correct?

Comment: This is correct - first to generate a header with a blank checksum, second to generate a header with the correct checksum